# Probability that a subset relation is also a function

Tags: functions

Given the set of numbers $N = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, and also the set of letters $L = \{A,B,C,D...,Y,Z\}$, Of the number of relations that can be defined from all possible subsets of $L$ to all possible subsets of $N$, what is the probability that a given relation is also a function? Express your answer as a fraction in simplest form.

I can use the Cartesian product to get the denominator of $2^{260}$, and find the number of functions for each subset individually using $N^L$, but then I would need to find all of the subsets possible. Is there a way faster to find the number of functions from all possible subsets?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be finite sets with cardinalities at least $1$.

The number of *relations* from $A$ to $B$ is $2^{|A||B|}$ while the number of *functions* $f:A\rightarrow B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$. Assuming each relation is equally likely to be chosen, the probability that a randomly selected relation from $A$ to $B$ is a function is $\frac{|B|^{|A|}}{2^{|A||B|}}$. Now take $A=2^L,B=2^N$ to get your answer.

Here, $2^L,2^N$ are the *power sets* of $L,N$ respectively. Note we have $|2^L|=2^{|L|}$ and $|2^N|=2^{|N|}$.

Comment: I don't understand why we are using 2^L and 2^N now. I plugged this into a calculator and it gives me 1/(2^68048388096), which rounds down to 0. I used L as 26 and N as 10.

Comment: The question asks for the probability that a relation from *the collection of subsets* of $L$ to *the collection of subsets* of $N$ is a function. Your calculation examines the probability that a relation $L$ to $N$ is a function.

Comment: Its important to keep in mind that an arbitrary relation from the collection of subsets of $L$ to the collection of subsets of $N$ is a subset of $$2^L \times 2^N=\big\{(X,Y):X\subseteq L, Y\subseteq N\big\}$$